# Change Series plotorder or legend entry order across different ChartGroups

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-charts

Office 365

I have a combination chart in powerpoint.  One series is column type, and the other three are lines.  They are all in the primary Y axis.  The X-axis is of category type (text labels)

Here is an example on how Powerpoint is structuring the chart

```
ChartGroup | Chart Type | PlotOrder | Legend | Correct Order 
1          |    Column  |  1        |    B   |       2
2          |    Line    |  1        |    A   |       1
2          |    Line    |  2        |    C   |       3
2          |    Line    |  3        |    D   |       4
```

Currently, the legend is being displayed like this

```
B A C D
```

I need the legend to be shown as

```
A B C D
```

This means that the legend A would be displayed before B even if it's in another chartgroup with a higher index than B's chartgroup.

I'm adding data snapshots and visual examples of what is happening:
Here is the dummy data I'm using:

[image: Dummy Data]

This is the initial order of series, when all of them are the same type and in the same ChartGroup, the order of the Series Legend are as required.

[image]

But then when I change the Series 1 Value type from Line to Column, this is what happens, a new chartgroup is created, and the Series1 Value is put at the beginning:

[image]

Even the Chart Order in the Data Source Window is as it was in the beginning:
[image]

And the formula for the Series1 Value still puts it's order as 2:
`=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$17,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$17,**2**)`

Is it possible to move Series1 Goal Legend from the second position to the first position when it's in different ChartGroups?

I'm thinking of some ideas:

1. adding a dummy series in the line charts ChartGroup to Display Series1 Value legend in the second position, and just delete the Legend from the Column Chart
2. Is it possible to add a fill below line charts to make it look like a column chart?

Any suggestion is welcome,

Thanks,

Comment: When creating a chart, it seems that you can create "A" first in the series.
We need your specific data so We can test it.

Comment: Thanks! i will post my sample code and data tomorrow mornin.  best regards

Comment: @Dy.Lee question has been updated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized your problem. As the charts are grouped, the display of the legend changes, so it is unlikely that the chart and the legend will be linked.

So I decided to use shortcuts. I made two macro charts with the correct legend and a modified chart, and copied only the legend part of the first chart, and made a macro to paste as a picture in the legend part of the second chart. There is a flaw in the resolution.

### Work process

[image]

### Result image

[image]

### code

```
Sub ModifyCahrtLegend()
    Dim Cht1 As Chart, Cht2 As Chart, Cht3 As Chart
    Dim Shp As Shape, Shp1 As Shape, Shp2 As Shape, Shp3 As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim fn As String
    Dim obj As ChartObject
    Dim l, t, w, h
    Dim cl, tb, ct
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Variant

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each obj In Ws.ChartObjects
        obj.Delete
    Next obj
    With Ws
        Set rngX = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rngHeader = .Range("b1")
    End With

    a = Array(1, 0, 2, 3)
    r = rngX.Rows.Count

    Set Shp1 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart(, Range("g1").Left, 100, 500, 300)
    Set Cht1 = Shp1.Chart

    With Cht1
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        For i = 0 To 3
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .XValues = rngX
                .Values = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i)).Offset(1).Resize(r)
                .Name = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i))
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Set Shp2 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart(, Range("g1").Left, 100, 500, 300)
    Set Cht2 = Shp2.Chart


    With Cht2
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        For i = 0 To 3
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .XValues = rngX
                .Values = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i)).Offset(1).Resize(r)
                .Name = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i))
            End With
        Next i
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection(2)
        With Srs
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        End With
    End With

    With Cht1
        t = .Legend.Top
        l = .Legend.Left
        h = .Legend.Height
        w = .Legend.Width
        ' .CopyPicture
    End With

    '** picture editing
    Cht1.CopyPicture

    Range("C23").Select
    Ws.Pictures.Paste
    n = Ws.Shapes.Count
    Set Shp = Ws.Shapes(n)

    With Shp1
        cl = (.Width - w) / 2
        cb = .Height - t - h
        ct = .Height - h - cb
    End With

    With Shp
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = cl
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = cl
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = ct
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = cb
    End With

    Set Cht3 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
     Set obj = Cht3.Parent
    With obj
        .Top = t
        .Left = l
        .Height = h
        .Width = w
        .ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

    Shp.CopyPicture
    Cht3.Paste
    fn = "legend.png"
    Cht3.Export fn, "PNG"

    Shp.Delete
    obj.Delete
    Shp1.Delete
    Set Shp = Cht2.Shapes.AddPicture(fn, msoFalse, msoCTrue, l, t, w, h)
    Kill fn

End Sub
```

However, the chart created in this way is deformed when resizing, so it would be better to make a chart by setting the width and height.

### Code 2

```
Sub testChart()

    ModifyLegend 500, 200 '<~~ set width, Height

End Sub
Sub ModifyLegend(myW, myH)
    Dim Cht1 As Chart, Cht2 As Chart, Cht3 As Chart
    Dim Shp As Shape, Shp1 As Shape, Shp2 As Shape, Shp3 As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim fn As String
    Dim obj As ChartObject
    Dim l, t, w, h
    Dim cl, tb, ct
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Variant

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each obj In Ws.ChartObjects
        obj.Delete
    Next obj
    With Ws
        Set rngX = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rngHeader = .Range("b1")
    End With

    a = Array(1, 0, 2, 3)
    r = rngX.Rows.Count

    Set Shp1 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart(, Range("g1").Left, 100, myW, myH)
    Set Cht1 = Shp1.Chart

    With Cht1
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        For i = 0 To 3
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .XValues = rngX
                .Values = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i)).Offset(1).Resize(r)
                .Name = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i))
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Set Shp2 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart(, Range("g1").Left, 100, myW, myH)
    Set Cht2 = Shp2.Chart


    With Cht2
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        For i = 0 To 3
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .XValues = rngX
                .Values = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i)).Offset(1).Resize(r)
                .Name = rngHeader.Offset(0, a(i))
            End With
        Next i
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection(2)
        With Srs
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        End With
    End With

    With Cht1
        t = .Legend.Top
        l = .Legend.Left
        h = .Legend.Height
        w = .Legend.Width
        ' .CopyPicture
    End With

    '** picture editing
    Cht1.CopyPicture

    Range("C23").Select
    Ws.Pictures.Paste
    n = Ws.Shapes.Count
    Set Shp = Ws.Shapes(n)

    With Shp1
        cl = (.Width - w) / 2
        cb = .Height - t - h
        ct = .Height - h - cb
    End With

    With Shp
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = cl
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = cl
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = ct
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = cb
    End With

    Set Cht3 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
     Set obj = Cht3.Parent
    With obj
        .Top = t
        .Left = l
        .Height = h
        .Width = w
        .ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

    Shp.CopyPicture
    Cht3.Paste
    fn = "legend.png"
    Cht3.Export fn, "PNG"

    Shp.Delete
    obj.Delete
    Shp1.Delete
    Set Shp = Cht2.Shapes.AddPicture(fn, msoFalse, msoCTrue, l, t, w, h)
    Kill fn

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  Currently I convinced the managers that the legend order could be altered so we can generate the charts without code changes.  However I'll give it a go ahead and try your code because... you know mgrs, change their mind every week.  Anyhow... if everything goes OK, I will mark your answer as accepted by the end of the week.